# How to apply a fabric.Text object property to a fabric.CurvedText object?

Tags: fabricjs

I am using fabric.js 4.5.0 version
I am converting fabric.Text object to fabric.CurvedText object.
problem is that The fabric.Text object property is not applied after it has been transferred to fabric.CurvedText object

Comment: CurvedText isn't a valid fabric object type. Are you using an extension of some kind?

Comment: @melchiar, Thanks for reply
i am following this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/av01d/4p0syzw3/

Comment: You'll need to edit your question and provide a working code example showing your specific issue of anyone is going to be able to help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first create fabric.Text object

```
var text = new fabric.Text('Testing,{
        strokeWidth: 0,
        stroke:"#ffffff",
        paintFirst: "stroke",
        fill: defaultTextColor,
        fontFamily: fontFamily,
        fontSize: defaultFontSize,
        typeOfObject: "text",
        charSpacing:0
});
activeCanvas.add(text);
activeCanvas.setActiveObject(text);
activeCanvas.renderAll();
```

now apply the shadow property to fabric.Text object

```
activeCanvas.getActiveObject().set('shadow',{
    color: 'black',
    blur: 10,
    offsetX: 10,
    offsetY: 0
});
activeCanvas.renderAll();
```

then convert fabric.Text ot fabric.TextCurved

```
activeCanvas.getActiveObject().set(new fabric.TextCurved(activeCanvas.getActiveObject().text, {
    type: 'text-curved',
    diameter: 360,
    kerning: 0,
    fontFamily: 'Arial'
    fontSize: 32,
    top: 395,
    left:405,
    strokeStyle: null,
    strokeWidth: 0,
    shadow:{
            color: activeCanvas.getActiveObject().shadow.color,
            blur: activeCanvas.getActiveObject().shadow.blur,
            offsetX: activeCanvas.getActiveObject().shadow.offsetX,
            offsetY: activeCanvas.getActiveObject().shadow.offsetY,
            opacity: activeCanvas.getActiveObject().shadow.opacity
   }
}));
activeCanvas.renderAll();
```